# What's an interesting or creative name for the chat room?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, 7-questions, chat

Our chat room is currently named

> [Ethereum](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34620/ethereum)

This is quite generic and I would like to change it to something more creative. Something that is both clever and somehow Ethereum-specific.

Some examples of other sites:

- Bitcoin.SE: `Mempool`
- Superuser: `Root Access`
- Space: `The Pod Bay`

And so on. Do you have any creative idea for a new name? Post it below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by @arodriguezdonaire, what about:

> **Whisper**

Whisper, to the `shh` [communication protocol](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper).  :-)

Comment: Let me up vote it twice...

Answer (score 3):

Make it academic, serious like. "chat" is too casual, non-serious.

**ETHought**

Serious subject serious discussion (although all nonsense banter is welcome of course)

:-))

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
{ EthCetera }
```

Comment: Uh, I like that :)

Answer (score 1):

"Ethereum Discussion" would be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 1):

From [r/ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4e9rn7/meta_whats_an_interesting_or_creative_name_for/d1yxhg0)

> The nEthwork

by *FractalDynamics*.

Answer (score 0):

I propose Chethereum ;>) more smileys to make it 30 chars `(^)'

Answer (score 0):

`EtherChat` seems to be obvious but it's very straightforward.

`AlethChat`, `Whisper chat` (1 vote), `Decentralized chat` could be other options.

Comment: Uh, I like `Whisper` pretty much. Good idea.

Comment: I'll edit the post with the number of votes of everyone who comments. :)

Comment: Ok, in general it would be better to have one idea per answer. To clarify: Whisper or Whisper chat? :)

Comment: Both are cool. I whould prefer whisper chat but I'd not cry if it was only called Whisper

Answer (score 0):

`txpool` - messages with too high a transaction nonce float around forever and ever - [What happens when a transaction nonce is too high?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/what-happens-when-a-transaction-nonce-is-too-high) .

Answer (score 0):

How about the "`DevPool`"?

There are a lot of prior references to "Dev" in Ethereum's assets e.g. DEVCON0/1/2 and the network protocol devP2P.

I also like Whisper :)

Answer (score 0):

From [r/ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4e9rn7/meta_whats_an_interesting_or_creative_name_for/d1z48jd)

> { EtherStack }

by *Innovator256*.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking in:

```
{ ETHalk }
```